# reusing the same table across several views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Just learning rails and looking for best practices help. I have the same data table that is reused across several different views (index, search results) for my controller. In an attempt to keep it DRY I have the table code in a helper method using html<< for table HTML.

I realize that now I've pulled a chunk of my HTML into the controller which I'm not a big fan of. How is this situation of having a chunk of HTML you plan to reuse across several views handled best?

Thanks!

Comment: You can handle it with rails like klump suggests (which is fine) or you can handle it with javascript and use a templating language like handlebars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want are partials. You put the partials in the same folder as the views, but partials start with an underscore (e.g: `app/views/user/_my_partial.html.erb`). In this partial you can put the shared HTML code, and access it from the view with:

```
<%= render "my_partial" %>
```

Yes you skip the underscore when you access the partial.

See the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for more information on partials.